# setPropertyActionListener within commandlink not working

Tags: jpa, primefaces

The datatable displays entries that I intend to be able to edit. In order to do so, I use a commandlink to open a dialog box. setPropertyActionListener sets the `CostingType` object that should be able to be modified from within the dialog box. However, the dialog box isn't able to get the object's variables or save them. Instead, it shows an empty object and clicking on the edit button(after keying in fields) shows the requiredMessage warnings instead. `checkEdit()` (which exists solely for debug purposes) isn't being called either.

HTML:

```
<h:form id="costingTypeForm" >
<p:tabView id="tabView">
<p:tab id="tab1" title="Costing Type">
<h:form id="costingTypeForm" >              
                <p:tabView id="tabView">
                <p:tab id="tab1" title="Costing Type">                                          
                    <p:dataTable
                            id="costingTypeTable"
                            value="#{costingTypeBean.costingTypeList}"
                            var="costingType"
                            rows="#{psmsProp['psms.dataTable.rows']}"
                            paginator="true"
                            paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {CurrentPageReport}"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="#{psmsProp['psms.dataTable.rowsPerPage']}"
                            currentPageReportTemplate="Displaying {startRecord}-{endRecord} out of {totalRecords}"
                            style="width:80%; text-align:center;"
                            sortBy="#{costingType.name}"
                            sortMode="single" >

                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                Costing Type

                                <p:commandButton
                                    value="Add"
                                    oncomplete="PF('addCostingTypeDialog').show()"
                                    update="costingTypeForm:tabView:addCostingTypeForm"
                                    icon="ui-icon-plus"
                                    style="float:right;" />

                                <div style="clear:both" />  
                            </f:facet> 
                            <p:column sortBy="#{costingType.name}"
                                filterBy="#{costingType.name}"
                                filterMatchMode="contains"
                                filterFunction="#{filterUtil.containsFilter}"
                                filterStyle="width:80%;"
                                headerText="Name">
                                <p:outputLabel id = "name" value="#{costingType.name}"  />
                            </p:column>                                             
                            <p:column headerText="Description">
                                <p:outputLabel id = "description" value="#{costingType.nameDesc}"  />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Budgeted">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Yes" rendered="#{costingType.budget}" />
                                <p:outputLabel value="No" rendered="#{not costingType.budget}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Deleted">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Yes" rendered="#{costingType.del}" />
                                <p:outputLabel value="No" rendered="#{not costingType.del}" />
                            </p:column>             
                            <p:column>
                                <p:commandLink
                                    oncomplete="PF('editCostingTypeDialog').show()"
                                    update=":costingTypeForm:tabView:editCostingTypeForm"
                                    value="Edit" action="#{costingTypeBean.checkEdit}">
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType}" value="#{costingType}"/>
                                </p:commandLink>                                    
                            </p:column>                                 
                            </p:dataTable>                              
                         <p:dialog
                            header="Edit Costing Type"
                            widgetVar="editCostingTypeDialog"
                            modal="true"
                            showEffect="slide"
                            hideEffect="fade"
                            resizable="false"
                            closable="false">
                            <p:outputPanel id="editCostingTypeForm">
                                <p:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" rendered="#{not empty costingTypeBean.editCostingType}">                                       
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <p:outputLabel value="Name:" />
                                        <p:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;" />
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Name is required" />

                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <p:outputLabel value="Description:" />
                                        <p:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;" />
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType.nameDesc}" required="true" requiredMessage="Description is required" />

                                    <p:outputLabel value="Budgeted:" />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType.budget}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="No" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                                    <h:outputLabel value="Deleted:" />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType.del}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="No" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </p:panelGrid>                                  
                                <p:commandButton
                                    value="Cancel"
                                    actionListener="#{costingTypeBean.cancelChange}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('editCostingTypeDialog').hide();"
                                    icon="ui-icon-close"
                                    style="float:right;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" />                                  
                                <p:commandButton
                                    value="Edit"
                                    actionListener="#{costingTypeBean.updateCostingType}"
                                    oncomplete="if(args.update) PF('editCostingTypeDialog').hide();"
                                    update=":costingTypeForm:messages @(.ui-datatable)"
                                    icon="ui-icon-disk"
                                    style="float:right;margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" />
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </p:dialog>
<p:dialog
                            header="Add New CostingType"
                            widgetVar="addCostingTypeDialog"
                            modal="true"
                            showEffect="slide"
                            hideEffect="fade"
                            resizable="false"
                            closable="false">
                            <p:outputPanel id="addCostingTypeForm">
                                <p:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <p:outputLabel value="Name" />
                                        <p:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;" />
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{costingTypeBean.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter name" />                                        
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <p:outputLabel value="Description:" />
                                        <p:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;" />
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{costingTypeBean.nameDesc}" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Engine Type" />
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:outputLabel value="Budgeted:" />
                                        <p:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;" />
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:selectOneRadio value="#{costingTypeBean.budgeted}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="No" />
                                    </p:selectOneRadio>
                                    <h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:outputLabel value="Deleted:" />
                                        <p:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;" />
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:selectOneRadio value="#{costingTypeBean.deleted}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="No" />
                                    </p:selectOneRadio>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                                <p:commandButton
                                    value="Cancel"
                                    actionListener="#{costingTypeBean.cancelChange}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('addCostingTypeDialog').hide();"

                                    icon="ui-icon-close"
                                    style="float:right;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" />                                  
                                <p:commandButton
                                    value="Save"
                                    actionListener="#{costingTypeBean.addCostingType}"
                                    oncomplete="if(args.add) PF('addCostingTypeDialog').hide(); else PF('addCostingTypeDialog').show();"
                                    update="@form @(.ui-datatable)"
                                    icon="ui-icon-disk"
                                    style="float:right;margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" />

                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </p:dialog> 
</p:tab>                                        
                       </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Backing bean:

```
@Component
 @Scope("view")
 public class CostingTypeBean{

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CostingTypeBean.class);

private long costingTypeId;    
private boolean budgeted, deleted;          
private String name, nameDesc;

private CostingType costingType; 
private CostingType editCostingType;

private List<CostingType> costingTypeList;

@Autowired
private CostingTypeService costingTypeService;

/*
getters and setters
*/
// dialog edit
public void updateCostingType(ActionEvent event) {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if(editCostingType!=null) {
            costingTypeService.saveOrUpdate(editCostingType);
            context.addCallbackParam("update", true);
        }

        else
            context.addCallbackParam("update", false);
 }

 //debug method
 public void checkEdit() {
    LOGGER.debug("Edit listener");
    ViewUtil.showInfo("Edit dialog triggered");
    System.out.println("Edit listener");
}
```

What should I do to get `editCostingTypeDialog` to reflect the fields of of the `CostingType` object and be able to read the values keyed in the input text areas?

Comment: Does `editCostingType` get a value after clicking the commandLink or is it null?

Comment: @Holger It's null

Comment: Then I'll undelete my downvoted answer. It would be nice if you upvote it, if it's helpful for you.

Comment: I just tested a `<f:setPropertyActionListener` in my dataTable. It should not send null to your `setEditCostingType()`. But it gets called **after** `checkEdit` of the surrounding commandLink. If you click a 2nd time, your editCostingType should be not null. That's not helpful, but you can test it.

Comment: @Holger An actionListener is not called after an action.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine. All I had to do was to modify some of the `update=` attributes (as I was getting exceptions about destination components not being found). After populating with some random data and using your above code I get the following;

[image]

I tested with both PrimeFaces 6.1 and 6.2 on Mojarra 2.3.3.99. The backing bean callback for the edit button in the dialog is also being called properly.

So the next thing to check - which JSF implementation are you using? Is it Mojarra or MyFaces ? which version ? Maybe you are hitting upon some bug in your specific implementation. There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code.

While I'm at it, I might as well post the complete code (including my modifications);

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Costing type Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="costingTypeForm" >              
            <p:tabView id="tabView">
                <p:tab id="tab1" title="Costing Type">                                          
                    <p:dataTable
                        id="costingTypeTable"
                        value="#{costingTypeBean.costingTypeList}"
                        var="costingType"
                        paginator="true"
                        style="width:80%; text-align:center;"
                        sortMode="single" >

                        <f:facet name="header">  
                            Costing Type
                            <p:commandButton value="Add" oncomplete="PF('addCostingTypeDialog').show()" update="@form" icon="ui-icon-plus" style="float:right;" />
                            <div style="clear:both" />  
                        </f:facet> 
                        <p:column sortBy="#{costingType.name}"
                              filterBy="#{costingType.name}"
                              filterMatchMode="contains"
                              filterFunction="#{filterUtil.containsFilter}"
                              filterStyle="width:80%;"
                              headerText="Name">
                            <p:outputLabel id = "name" value="#{costingType.name}"  />
                        </p:column>                                             
                        <p:column headerText="Description">
                            <p:outputLabel id = "description" value="#{costingType.nameDesc}"  />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Budgeted">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Yes" rendered="#{costingType.budget}" />
                            <p:outputLabel value="No" rendered="#{not costingType.budget}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Deleted">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Yes" rendered="#{costingType.del}" />
                            <p:outputLabel value="No" rendered="#{not costingType.del}" />
                        </p:column>             
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandLink
                                oncomplete="PF('editCostingTypeDialog').show()"
                                update=":costingTypeForm:tabView:editCostingTypeForm"
                                value="Edit" action="#{costingTypeBean.checkEdit}">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType}" value="#{costingType}"/>
                            </p:commandLink>                                    
                        </p:column>                                 
                    </p:dataTable>                              
                    <p:dialog
                        header="Edit Costing Type"
                        widgetVar="editCostingTypeDialog"
                        modal="true"
                        showEffect="slide"
                        hideEffect="fade"
                        resizable="false"
                        closable="false">
                        <p:outputPanel id="editCostingTypeForm">
                            <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{not empty costingTypeBean.editCostingType}">                                       
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="Name:" />
                                    <p:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                                <p:inputText value="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Name is required" />

                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="Description:" />
                                    <p:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                                <p:inputText value="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType.nameDesc}" required="true" requiredMessage="Description is required" />

                                <p:outputLabel value="Budgeted:" />
                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType.budget}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="No" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>

                                <h:outputLabel value="Deleted:" />
                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType.del}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="No" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </p:panelGrid>                                  
                            <p:commandButton
                                value="Cancel"
                                actionListener="#{costingTypeBean.cancelChange}"
                                oncomplete="PF('editCostingTypeDialog').hide();"
                                icon="ui-icon-close"
                                style="float:right;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" />                                  
                            <p:commandButton
                                value="Edit"
                                actionListener="#{costingTypeBean.updateCostingType}"
                                oncomplete="if(args.update) PF('editCostingTypeDialog').hide();"
                                update="@form"
                                icon="ui-icon-disk"
                                style="float:right;margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" />
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:dialog>
                </p:tab>                                        
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And here is the backing bean (example uses Lombok and Apache Commons);

```
@Data
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CostingTypeBean implements Serializable {
    private CostingType costingType;
    private CostingType editCostingType;
    private List<CostingType> costingTypeList;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        costingTypeList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final String name = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
            final String nameDesc = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
            final boolean budget = RandomUtils.nextBoolean();
            final boolean del = RandomUtils.nextBoolean();

            costingTypeList.add(new CostingType(name, nameDesc, budget, del));
        }
    }

    public void updateCostingType(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("update!");
    }

    public void checkEdit() {
        System.out.println("Edit listener");
    }

    public void cancelChange() {
        System.out.println("Cancel");
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class CostingType {
        private String name;
        private String nameDesc;
        private boolean budget;
        private boolean del;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this can be of some help.

Comment: I'm using Primefaces 5.2, Hibernate 4.2.6 and Spring 3.2.5. The most frustrating thing about this is how nothing seems to be wrong yet it doesn't work.

Comment: @NicholasLeong You'll have to diff the documents .. If you look in your example you are defining `h:form` and `p:tab` multiple times at the top of the XHTML document. But I guess this might be a typo? Other than that I didn't really change much. Mostly minor tweaks to get it to work with the backing bean. Is my version working for you ? I did not try with PrimeFaces 5.2. So maybe that is causing your issues ?

Comment: @NicholasLeong The update call from the edit link in the table (`update=":costingTypeForm:tabView:editCostingTypeForm"`) which refetches the backing bean values in the dialog are identical... I would suspect either PrimeFaces 5.x or your JSF version/mplementation is being the culprit here.

Comment: I stumbled upon what was causing the problem. I had a second dialog( `addCostingTypeDialog`), in which two fields had `required` and `requiredMessage`. I originally thought that part of the html was not relevant so I left it out but I've just put it back in. Removing those modifiers solved the problem. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug in PrimeFaces (I think).
I searched with many tests in a minimal test application. It's not possible to use following constellation:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="myVar".....
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" listener="#{bean.doWork(myVar)}"/>
```

`bean.doWork()` will always be called with a null pointer.

Glassfish 4.1.1
PrimeFaces 6.2

I think your problem is the same.

Comment: This is not correct. The above code from the OP works just fine with a few minor changes.

Comment: That's nice. I look forward to your answer. Maybe it helps me too.

Comment: The example code does pretty much the exact same thing; https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml However - proper usage here is to do `listener="#{bean.doWork}"` and handle the `SelectEvent` instead (which includes more information than just sending in `var`. The OP is doing `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{costingTypeBean.editCostingType}" value="#{costingType}"/>`. This is completely correct and should (and does) work just fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried it. I inserted `<p:commandButton value="Button" actionListener="#{testbean.selWork()}" ajax="true" partialSubmit="true" process="@this">
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testbean.selected}" value="#{item}"/>
</p:commandButton>` in my dataTable and `setSelected()` gets called with a value. But it gets called **after** the `actionListener` of the button...?

Comment: Correct. Action listeners (inlcuding property action listeners) are processed first and in the order they are delcared on the component. You are defining the actionListener of the component first. If you want to access the property set via `f:setPropertyActionListener`from within an event/action of the button - use `action=`. Action listeners should be used to handle setup of states and/or validation checks (as they can interrupt the main action). Use the action attribute to invoke business logic.